# MySQL sort multiple date columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 3 key fields

- start_date
- end_date
- date

`start_date` and `end_date` are for events that will span multiple dates. `date` is for a single day event.

How can I sort all dates by start date OR date, whichever applies. Assume there is a 4th field, `multiple_day_event`, which is either "yes" or "no".

Comment: I would omit both the `date` and `multiple_day_event` columns -- they're redundant, and the query will be easier without them.  No big deal to set single day events with the same end date.  But I hope those columns include time...

Comment: By "database" you mean "table"?

Comment: Thanks for editing for readability OMG Ponies, but how is it helpful to cut out the part where I say "I know the best way is probably to switch to using start_date and end_date even for single day events, but I'm just interested in how you would accomplish this with a query." and then turn around and offer it as advice?

Comment: And yes, I meant table... coffee has not yet taken effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like [`IFNULL(START_DATE,DATE)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) [`IF(MULTIPLE_DAY_EVENT='yes',START_DATE, DATE)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) Or [case, when](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html):

```
CASE multiple_day_event
    WHEN 'yes' THEN START_DATE
    -- WHEN 'taco' THEN 'salsa???' Or any other when.
    ELSE DATE
END CASE
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT IF(multiple_day_event, start_date, date) AS mdate ORDER BY mdate`